# How to review changes before making a record go live. Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I need an efficient solution for the following scenario.

We allow users to add products to our website, we check each product before making it live, so the issue is, once a product is created and the user updates it, we do not want changes to go live until we review them, product will still be visible but with old information. How to solve this issue, am using Laravel framework with MySQL & mongoDB.

**1 Solution:** Create mirror tables associated with products and save the changes in them and move to the live tables when quality check is passed. But it can be an issue to maintain all the tables associated with product and replicate and update them.

Comment: A simpel solution would be: save the change to a `change` table, if approved update the original.

Comment: But is there any thing in MySQL that if a table is updated ( I mean a column is added or removed ) the change in table structure is applied to the "change" tables?

Comment: Why would it need to change the table structure of the `change` table? Let's call that table, `change_product` in this case to make it less confusing.

Comment: I mean if I add a column to original table I have to update the change_product table too, that is hard to track and as a product table has many sub tables so all sub tables will have a change table and it can become messy.